# R - Concatenate cell in dataframe, by group, depending on another cell value

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, reshape, string-concatenation

I have a dataset of the following type (first row is the header):

- `content` is always text
- `merge` is always a logical

```
id1  id2  start_line end_line content           merge
A    B    1          1        "aaaa"            TRUE
A    B    4          4        "aa mm"           TRUE
A    B    5          5        "boool"           TRUE
A    B    6          6        "omw"             TRUE
C    D    6          6        "hear!"           TRUE
C    D    7          7        " me out!"        TRUE
C    D    21         21       "hello"           FALSE
```

**Problem:** I need to merge following a very specific criteria:

- Rows that have `merge = FALSE` must remain as is
- Rows that have: same `id1`, same `id2` and consecutive `start_line`:

  - Need to be appended on the column `content`
  - The `end_line` value needs to change to the last row

So, the expected result would be:

```
id1  id2  start_line end_line content             merge
A    B    1          1        "aaaa"              TRUE
A    B    4          6        "aa mm boool omw"   TRUE
C    D    6          7        "hear!  me out!"    TRUE
C    D    21         21       "hello"             FALSE
```

Notice in the example that:

- The minimal merge is with two lines (example of ids: C-D, originally 6th and 7th rows)
- There can be multiple lines to merge (example of ids A-B, originally rows 2nd, 3rd, 4th)

I have attempted a very large, and inefficient series of loops, that only merge two lines. That is why I am not posting my attempt here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(id1, id2, grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start_line) > 1))) %>%
 summarise(start_line = first(start_line), 
           end_line = last(end_line), 
           content = paste(content, collapse = " "), 
            merge = any(merge))


#  id1   id2     grp start_line end_line content         merge
#  <chr> <chr> <int>      <int>    <int> <chr>           <lgl>
#1 A     B         1          1        1 aaaa            TRUE 
#2 A     B         2          4        6 aa mm boool omw TRUE 
#3 C     D         2          6        7 hear!  me out!  TRUE 
#4 C     D         3         21       21 hello           FALSE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C"), id2 = c("B", 
"B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D"), start_line = c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 21L), end_line = c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 21L), content = c("aaaa", 
"aa mm", "boool", "omw", "hear!", " me out!", "hello"), merge = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: It works! Genius! Just for the record,  I didn't realise that my dataset wasn't ordered. So a first run or your solution didn't work. I needed to do: `
data <- data[with(data, order(id1, id2, start_line)), ]` first, to order the dataframe. After that, your solution worked perfectly.