# R: Replacing data by group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a dataset of this style:

```
id1  id2  start_line end_line content   
A    B    1          1        "aaaa" 
A    B    4          4        "aa mm" 
A    B    5          5        "boool"
A    B    6          6        "omw"   
C    D    6          6        "hear!" 
C    D    7          7        " me out!"
C    D    21         21       "hello"
```

I need to mutate this several times, with specific criteria. In particular, rows that have the same `id1`, same `id2` and consecutive `start_line`:

- The `start_line` needs to be changed to be the first one in the group
- The `end_line` value needs to change to the last row
- A new column `real_line` needs to have the original `start_line`
- A new numeric `cid` line with a numeric ID calculated by group of `id1`, `id2`, `start_line`, `end_line`

So, the expected result would be:

```
id1  id2  start_line end_line content      real_line   cid
A    B    1          1        "aaaa"        1          1
A    B    4          6        "aa mm"       4          2
A    B    4          6        "boool"       5          2
A    B    4          6        "omw"         6          2
C    D    6          7        "hear!"       6          3
C    D    6          7        " me out!"    7          3
C    D    21         21       "hello"       21         4
```

I can add `real_line` by simply copying the original column, but I don't know how to replace `start_line` and `end_line` without summarising.

Comment: I explained that in my post: "In particular, rows that have the same id1, same id2 and consecutive start_line:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group by 'id1', 'id2', then create the 'cid' based on the

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
     group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start_line)  != 1)), 
           .add = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(real_line = start_line, 
       start_line = first(start_line), end_line = last(end_line)) %>%
    mutate(cid = cur_group_id()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
#  id1   id2   start_line end_line content      cid real_line
#  <chr> <chr>      <int>    <int> <chr>      <int>     <int>
#1 A     B              1        1 "aaaa"         1         1
#2 A     B              4        6 "aa mm"        2         4
#3 A     B              4        6 "boool"        2         5
#4 A     B              4        6 "omw"          2         6
#5 C     D              6        7 "hear!"        3         6
#6 C     D              6        7 " me out!"     3         7
#7 C     D             21       21 "hello"        4        21
```

Comment: I can't run this, because it says that "column cid can't be modified because it's a grouping variable"

Comment: @Mel Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.2’` on `R 4.0.3`

Comment: @Mel If it is showing issue, then you can have the first `group_by(grp=` and later in `mutate(cid = cur_group_id())`

Comment: Yeah, my `dplyr` was epochs old apparently. That did it!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem was that I wasn't ungrouping.

So based on [R - Concatenate cell in dataframe, by group, depending on another cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108159/r-concatenate-cell-in-dataframe-by-group-depending-on-another-cell-value)

I did:

```
mydf$real_line <- mydf$start_line


mydf %>% 
      group_by(id1, id2, grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(start_line) > 1))) %>% 
      mutate(start_line = first(start_line), end_line = last(end_line)) %>%
      ungroup()

mydf$grp <- NULL
```

And this generated the result I needed, but without the ID per group.